# Programming: adafruit Fona gprs+sms?

Tags: python, r, raspberry-pi, gsm, gprs

I am working on a project that requires a GPRS connection and sending SMS at the same time.

I am using Raspberry Pi and adafruit fona.

I established the GPRS connection following this [FONA Tethering to Raspberry Pi](https://learn.adafruit.com/fona-tethering-to-raspberry-pi-or-beaglebone-black/setup) tutorial.

I am not using ttyAMA0. I have changed this to `ttyUSB0` and then used USB to TTL connection.

I have successfully established the GPRS connection, but the problem is that when my Python code tries to send an SMS using an AT command it will not work.

This is how I am sending the SMS:

```
modem=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',115200,timeout=5)
modem.write("AT+CMGF=1\r".encode())
time.sleep(1)
modem.write('AT+CMGS="00*******"\r\n'.encode())
time.sleep(1)
modem.write("message\r".encode())
time.sleep(1)
modem.write(ascii.ctrl('z').encode())
time.sleep(1)
```

Why is the code only sending SMS if the GPRS is not working?

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using the fona since about 1 year for sms and http posts. SMS to receive commands and posts to send updates to the cloud.

First to receive an sms reliably fona has to be turned on for 20 seconds (I'm running my system on solar power - so I completely turn fona off when it is not needed).

Sending an SMS is possible faster then 20 seconds but I anyway came up with the following duty cycle when turning on the fona as a best practice:

1. fona is turned on
2. gprs is turned on
3. post data is sent (takes a few seconds)
4. turn off gprs
5. wait until at least 20 seconds have passed since fona was turned on to make sure sms have been received
6. check for sms
7. send answer sms if required

So I think at the time turning off gprs was necessary for sms to be received or sent. It also consumer more power.